# Basic makefile program: in main Error undefined reference to "power"

Tags: c, makefile, header

Header lab3p2.h

```
#ifndef LAB3P2_H
#define LAB3P2_H

long power(int integer1, int integer2);

#endif
```

Power Function: lab3p2f1.c

```
#include "lab3p2.h"
#include <stdio.h>

long power(int integer1, int integer2){ 
    int i;
    long ret =(long) integer1;
    if(integer2 ==0)
    {
          ret = 1;
    }else{
          for( i =1 ; i < integer2; i++)
          {
                ret = ret * integer1;
          }
    } 
   return ret;
}
```

**Main: lab3p2.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "lab3p2.h"
/*Takes in integers from the command line and returns the power function result*/
int main(int argc, char **argv){
     int a = atoi( *(argv+1));
     int b = atoi( *(argv+2));
     int c =atoi( *(argv+3));
     long functionResult;

     functionResult = power(b,c);               
     printf("The result of the power function is %ld \n", functionResult);
}
```

MakeFile: makefile

```
all: lab3p2
mkprog: lab3p2.o lab3p2f1.o
    gcc lab3p2.o lab3p2f1.o -o lab3p2
lab3p2.o: lab3p2.c
    gcc -ansi -pedantic -c lab3p2.c
lab3p2f1.o: lab3p2f1.c
    gcc -ansi -pedantic -c lab3p2f1.c
clean:
    rm -rf *.o lab3p2
```

Why can the main not access the function?
Is something wrong with how I am compiling? 
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please show your build log. And note that C and C++ are different languages. Please use only the relevant tag (C in this case it seems).

Comment: Are you invoking your makefile with just `make` or `make mkprog`?

Comment: What makes you think `long` has a larger range than `int`? And don't spam tags. This is apparently compiled as C.

Comment: Also, you'd really want to check that `argc` is at least 4...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the rule for target `lab3p2`; i.e. `mkprog` should be `lab3p2`:

```
all: lab3p2

lab3p2: lab3p2.o lab3p2f1.o
        gcc lab3p2.o lab3p2f1.o -o lab3p2

lab3p2.o: lab3p2.c
        gcc -ansi -pedantic -c lab3p2.c

lab3p2f1.o: lab3p2f1.c
        gcc -ansi -pedantic -c lab3p2f1.c

clean:
        rm -rf *.o lab3p2
```

---

With your current `Makefile`, when you run `make` without arguments, you will get the following output:

```
% make
gcc -ansi -pedantic -c lab3p2.c
cc   lab3p2.o   -o lab3p2
lab3p2.o: In function `main':
lab3p2.c:(.text+0x6b): undefined reference to `power'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
<builtin>: recipe for target 'lab3p2' failed
make: *** [lab3p2] Error 1
```

What happens is that make tries to satisfy the first target (i.e. `all`); this then requires `lab3p2`. As make cannot find an *explicit* rule to build `lab3p2` it then tries an implicit one - it knows that one can build `foo` by linking `foo.o` into a program; thus it runs the command

```
cc   lab3p2.o   -o lab3p2
```

However, this command doesn't link in the `lab3p2f1.o` where the definition for `power` resides.

---

These implicit rules can be quite handy with simple projects; for example for your project, the Makefile for GNU make could be simply written as

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -ansi -pedantic

all: lab3p2

lab3p2: lab3p2.o lab3p2f1.o

clean:
        rm -rf *.o lab3p2
```

and make would automatically figure out how to build the `.o` from corresponding `.c` and that it should use the compiler from the `CC` variable, and pass arguments from the `CFLAGS`.